# Ionic best practice for counting category followers without user system

Tags: angular, ionic2

i'm working on cross-platform app using **ionic 2**

my question is about how to count followers that chose to follow a category posts.

i have no users system in the app, so i have no user id to save it to my database to know if this user followed that category or not.

so, is there any way to get a unique ID for every devise and using it to save it into database to know which devise follows which category?

or it will be just add `followers` column into the category table into database and when any user click follow i will save the category id into user local storage then increment category followers by 1 ? but what if this user uninstalled the app? it will not decrements the followers

so, any one have any idea what is the best way for doing that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get device `UUID` from ionic which is a unique number for each device.

Here is the link of [ionic 2 docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device/) on how to get it.